# Rxjs observable versus observer 'semantics'

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, observers

since a few weeks I use Observables quite often and it is a true joy to have this in the toolbox.

However, I cannot seem to grasp the semantics/terminology illustrated by the following construct (just a theoretical example):

```
const o = Observable.create((observer: Observer<boolean>) => {
 observer.next(true);
 observer.error(false);
});
```

I understand that you need to pass in an argument to the anonymous function to make it happen, but why is this called an Observer of type Observer and why would you call next() and error() on this observer? Intuitively to me it is the observable that emits the values and pushes it to the observer. The above construct seems to turn this around.

Basically, would it not be more logical to have the following **pseudo** code:

```
const o = Observable.create(() => {
 this.next(true);
 this.error(false);
});
```

or, even more clearly:

```
const o = Observable.create(next: () => {... return true;}, error: () => { return false;});
```

Maybe a very rookie question, but I would love to get some insight.

Thanks!

Comment: With `arrow` functions, the context of `this` will always be the containing class, so it wouldn't work

Comment: yes (it was pseudo code) understood but the question is mainly why need to use observer.next() while it seems to be that the observable emits the value, so: obserable.next() is more logical

Comment: I think yours is a very legitimate question, a question I asked myself and still sometimes pops to my mind. The way I see it is that you use `next` on the Observer to say "Hey, Observer, here the next item I, the Observable, want to notify to you". Maybe it was more clear when it was called "onNext"? One more thing. You find `next` also on Subject. In this case `next` actually means "notify a new occurrence of event with its data to all the Observers which have subscribed to that Subject". Same applies to `error` and `complete`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Idd: the observer seems to be the representation of all subscribed observers (reminds me somewhat of a delegate in C#) and observer.next(value) than means: call the defined next(value) function on each of these observers and pass the value to these functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Observable-Observer*** pattern is a **Push** mechanism, means that it is the mission of Observable to notify Observer. Observable needs a reference to Observer to notify it about new emitions. Observable callbacks such as **onNext** and **onError** are the bridge between Observable-Observer so such callbacks exists in Observer and Observable will call them.

Comment: Still:  if it is a push mechanisme, is it not more logical to write: observable.next(); this would equal observable.push().  But ok, I think I am missing some technical info here. Thanks for your answer. I appreciate it truly.

Comment: push mechanism means that datasource (observable) will push new data to the listener (observer)

Comment: so I guess it means: call the next() method on the subscribed observers where observer.next() is mapped to callback next of each of the subscribed observers